# DNS / Split Zone Environment

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain, nslookup

i'm trying to configure a domain environment which has same internal and external domain name.

Say -  `Internal -- aishwarya.com = 192.168.50.100`

```
External -- aishwarya.com = 185.85.85.85
```

i've some external sub domains say

> e1.aishwarya.com e2.aishwarya.com e3.aishwarya.com

Now i have added a client in my internal domain say **i1.aishwarya.com** and has ip **192.168.50.102** with dns primary **192.168.50.100** and secondary say **8.8.8.8**

> ** **Problem** **

Problem : now when i try to resolve e1.aishwarya.com it says unable to resolve since this is a public dns url and it is searching internally since 192.168.50.100 is primary dns on client.

> **Work Around:**

i've to change my primary dns ip to 8.8.8.8 so that this resolves e1.aishwarya.com the problem here is this way it makes me difficult to join new clients to AD (192.168.50.100)

i've to add entries in forward lookup zone but the problem here is much manual effort and every entry needs to be updated always in forward lookup zone

> **What i want**

I'm looking for a solution that my external domain names should resolve with primary dns ip as internal dns server i.e 192.168.50.100

Thanks for Reading,
Have a Great Day Ahead.

Comment: Are you using windows to do the split DNS?

Comment: yes we've windows server internally, and on external we've the domain with the same name which has website hosted, the external sub domains are the url's for some servers placed in cloud, so nothing internal. i need internal dns only for centralising the environment but all servers are in cloud with external names, but i want my internal dns server to resolve all the external dns server url's which i can do by creating A records in dns forward zone but i need alternative since this involves lots of manual work

Answer (score 1):

In a split-horizon DNS arrangement

- All the internal clients *only* know about your internal DNS servers - e.g. an internal primary (master) and some internal secondaries (slaves) for resilience.
- Internal clients never know about external DNS servers such as 8.8.8.8
- The internal DNS servers need to be configured to know about hosts in both internal and externally visible subdomains of the organisations domain - since they believe themselves to be authoritative about those domains.
- The internal DNS servers are configured to *[forward](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730756(v=ws.11).aspx)* queries about other domains to external servers.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. so any other way besides adding A Record entries in forward zone ?? i've 500 sub domains so this involves lots of work besides this for every sub domain created in external dns, i've to create the A record entry in forward zone, i don't like this. any other method to automate ? like if the internal client(192.168.50.102) sends dns query to internal dns server (192.168.50.100) asking for external sub domain (e2.aishwarya.com) then my internal dns should forward it to 8.8.8.8 how can i achieve this ?

Comment: @Shafiq delegate the externally visible subdomains to the small set of  external DNS servers that are authoritative for those domains. Your NAT routers may need to support hairpinning. You may be able to use a wildcard NS record.